# How to use List widget inside scroll container in fyne?

Tags: go, fyne

Scroll collapses everytime i use list widget inside scroll container, if i use `label widget` then scroll container is `full width` and `full height` but when i use `list widget` it just collapses.

Not Working (Scroll collapses)

```
func ShowListDialog(win fyne.Window, messages []string){
    list := widget.NewList(
        func() int {
            return len(messages)
        },
        func() fyne.CanvasObject {
            return widget.NewLabel("label")
        },
        func(i widget.ListItemID, o fyne.CanvasObject) {
            o.(*widget.Label).SetText(messages[i])
        },
    )
    d := dialog.NewCustom("Messages", "Close" , container.NewScroll(list), win) 
    d.Resize(fyne.NewSize(500, 400))
    d.Show()
}
```

Working for label (scroll has full width&height)

```
func ShowLabelDialog(win fyne.Window, message string){
    d := dialog.NewCustom("Message", "Close", container.NewScroll(widget.NewLabel(message)), win) 
    d.Resize(fyne.NewSize(500, 400))
    d.Show()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The list widget already contains a scroll - removing the outer one should resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks! I've did as you said and it did show the scroll `d := dialog.NewCustom("Messages", "Close" , list, win)` but it is still showing minimum possible height & width and if i use `d.Resize(fyne.NewSize(500, 400))` then horizontal scroll vanishes.

Comment: This sounds correct isn’t it? Resizing the dialog wider abs there is now nothing to scroll?

Comment: Dialog is going to display content at minimum size, so Resize is the right thing if you want it larger

Comment: no there is content that's hidden (horizontally) and scroll isn't appearing after resize, may be the scroll layout doesn't gets updated after the dialog resize.

or is it possible to add `list` after the dialog resize?

Comment: It sounds like you found a bug :( please open an issue on the GitHub project so it will get resolved